# import en javascript en tiempo de ejecución con Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Tengo un fichero que hace un import a un archivo de rutas del entorno que no existe hasta que la aplicación está desplegada en el servidor. Necesito que ese import se resuelva cuando está en ejecución no en compilación.

¿Hay alguna forma de decirle a webpack que no intente resolver ese import y que lo deje tal cual en el archivo javascript?

El código sería éste

`import * as env from '/env.js';`

Y este es el error que me sale cuando compila

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que decirle a Webpack que es una librería "externa" al proyecto para que no intente importarla: Has de añadir algo como esto en el fichero webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    env: '/env'
  },
};
```

Tienes la documentación en https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: Ahora me devuelve este error: ERROR in main/main.js from Terser
Unexpected line terminator [main/main.js:174,17]